# EmberJS: Error when setting a collection property which is bound to a view in IE only

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an ember object with a collection property bound to a template. When I try to set this property like this:

```
processingJob.set("logMessages", updatedProcessingJob.logMessages)
```

I get this exception in IE only, all other browsers work fine:

> SCRIPT5022: assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

It's bound to the template like this:

```
{{#each content.logMessages}}
    {{#isWorkflowError}}
        <li class="error"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i> {{message}}</li>
    {{else}}
        <li><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i> {{message}}</li>
    {{/isWorkflowError}}
{{/each}}
```

When I remove the template I don't get the error. Should I be using a Ember.CollectionView or something? Or is this an IE bug?

Comment: Would be better if you could provide more code/details. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be golden.

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolution to this problem and posted it here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1525

I'm using SignalR to push updates to my ember app, my code to do this looks like:

```
App.ProcessingJobArray = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend
    init: ->
        @set("content", Ember.A())
        if $.connection
            @client = $.connection.processingJobHub
            @client.processingJobUpdated = (updatedProcessingJob) =>                
                processingJob = @get("content").find((item) ->
                    item.get("id") == updatedProcessingJob.id
                )
                if not processingJob
                    processingJob = App.ProcessingJob.create()
                    @get("content").pushObject(processingJob)
                processingJob.setProperties(updatedProcessingJob)
            $.connection.hub.start()
```

The updatedProcessingJob JSON object contains an array logMessages and in IE I was getting an error because there's no meta hash for this array. To fix the issue I did a deep copy of updatedProcessingJob:

```
updatedProcessingJob = $.extend(true, {}, updatedProcessingJob)
```